# Maintain Session attributte while open new url in webview Android

Tags: java, android, jsp, session, webview

I have a Java/Jsp web application where at search_list.jsp page I am setting the result in the session object like this --

```
<%

  Object resultdata = req.getSession().getAttribute("search_result");
  if(resultdata == null)
  { 
    resultdata  = (SearchResult)getSearchResult();
     request.getSession().setAttribute("search_result", resultdata);
 }

%>
```

From web browser when I hit another page and comeback to search_list.jsp retrieving of result object from session works fine , but same scenario always return > resultdata null in android native webview. Following is the code of webview from android native app.

```
public class HomeActivity implements OnClickListener {

  public WebView mWebView;
  public String sessionCookie =  null;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
              mWebView.loadUrl(appPrefer.getAppURL());          
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

   }

  public void saveSession()
         CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager =             CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    if(mWebView!=null)
    {
            sessionCookie = cookieManager.getCookie(getCurrentURLLoad());               

    } 

}

private void addSession(String url) 
  {                 
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager =  CookieSyncManager.createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);            
    if (sessionCookie != null) {            
            cookieManager.setCookie(url, sessionCookie);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();         
        }

 }
```

This is button click of native where (its kind of shortcut to go result back) i am loading search_list.jsp again for show result. But at web level we already search and shows results and viewing the profile.jsp page. So on click of native listview(url is search_list.jsp) I add session as follow:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getId().== R.id.listview) 
   {
  saveSession();
  mWebView.loadUrl(HOST_URL + SEARCH_LIST );
      addSession();
    }
 }
```

My problem is its saves/pass all other session cookie values but values set as request.session.attribute not come up they all are >null, after url changes on click from native at jsp level resultdata is always null.

**I have tried the method mention in answer, also tried the - https://gist.github.com/arpit/610754  way and I always see all my cookies correct value(which is already working on my posted que..) .. but Attribute set in HTTPRequest session is not there .. i donot think its part of cookie its a httpRequets attribute ( [HttpServletRequest->httpSession->setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) ) and my conclusion is its not come at Android webview OR httpclient side. Please someone let me know is that correct or there is a way to read the http request session attribute???**

Comment: y not you try from jsp side nt from android side

Comment: try to save session ? i donot get it.

Comment: Instead of `request.getSession().setAttribute()` you can directly write `session.setAttribute()` because session object is available in jsp

Comment: yes thats i know and if i do that way also my session attributes not pass in webview next url load.

Comment: hmm thts your solution dear

Comment: @DigveshPatel I am saving session at server side only but in native when i hit a menu button i want to go to specific url with all session to be intact in current state.

Comment: @neha yes but u keep track on last opened site list

Comment: yes that my problem i know current url at native and reading all session of it keeping it and pushing it with another url where i can see all other session values except which are set in session.attribute

Comment: why down vote for question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while debugging and understanding my problem more better I found following things :

**1)** If you set the object/value in request.getSession().setAttribute() that's saved at server side and not carry in the http req/res so its not possible to access them at native side.

**2)** But every server crate JSESSIONID that's the key to get data for every hit or unique hit at server memory.

So que is When I am saving all cookie and passing (which have the JSESSIONID cookie also) still why it's not able to get the correct data at server end??

SO found issue at my end: [not sure it's a common issue]

***That every time at native side user refresh or start webview fresh with URL (kind of on button click I just re-load url at webview with starting new activity and closing last activity).This always create new JSESSIONID at server side..*** ;( I try many way to pass cookie so it will not start new Session, even saved last JSESSIONID cookie and injected in new load url but nothing works. :-( ..

***So at last I have to add header/parameter in URL to indicate the server that native is reloading and session will be new so handle accordingly and donot show error of not found result.***